# probability of max numbers and last numbers in sequence

Tags: probability, statistics

If you have a sequence of 8 randomly generated real numbers in uniform distribution in the range of 1 - 10, where  *max*  = the two largest numbers in the sequence and  *last*   = the last two numbers in the sequence, how one figure out the probability that the product of  *max*  = the product of  *last*

Comment: Integers? Possibly duplicated numbers?

Comment: Real numbers, yes duplicates are possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability for any numbers to be repeated is zero. The product of the last two numbers is equal to the product of the largest two numbers if and only if the last two numbers are the largest two numbers. The probability for this is $\binom82^{-1}$.

Comment: thanks, what is that number with a precision of 10 decimals?

Comment: @banskybansky: Most computers have a calculator program. If you don't have one, you can use [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/). In case the problem is that you don't know the definition of binomial coefficients, you can find it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).